# What is the Windows 7 equivalent of bash's "export PS1" to set prompt color

Tags: windows-7, command-line

On Linux, I can set the prompt to a custom color by typing:

```
export PS1="\[\e[36;1m\][\u@\h \W]\$ \[\e[0m\]"
```

Is there a way to customize the color of the prompt on Windows 7? I'm not refering to the general text color of the command window, but just the prompt itself.

Comment: As far as I know, no cmd.exe does not offer that, though that works just fine in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

The standard windows command prompt does not support colored output, and I am not aware of any way to change the properties of the prompt itself. Basic ANSI color escape characters can be made to work in the standard Windows command prompt by using [ANSIcon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon), but I do not think the prompt itself can be changed.

You can easily change the prompt in powershell, however, by simply overriding the "prompt" function. A simple example:

```
#Replace default powershell prompt
function prompt
{
    Write-Host ("<" + $(pwd) + ">") -nonewline -foregroundcolor Blue
    return ' '
}
```

Produces a prompt consisting of the current directory in blue, like so:

[image: Basic powershell blue prompt]

Naturally you can add any other logic you would like to the prompt function.